# Sendy - Does Sendy Extension Available for OroCRM?

Tags: email, orocrm, campaign-monitor, sendy

We using OroCRM and run campaign, does Sendy extension available for OroCRM, if extension not  available any alternate way exits?

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the official OroCRM extensions in the [OroCRM Extension Marketplace](https://marketplace.oroinc.com/orocrm/).

There is no extension for Sandy, but as an alternative, you can use Dotmailer integration with OroCRM 4.1. If you are using OroCRM 3.1 or 2.6, there is also Mailchimp integration available.

Comment: How to set single mail id to all users, if admin users send mail,  from mail id should be admin@gmail.com

Comment: so you want all the emails be sent from the same email address, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Any help thanks @Andrey Yatsenko

Comment: Please create a separate question with steps to reproduce and the expected result. I tried to check it locally but there are still too many additional questions.

Comment: okay,  i have posted couple of question, could you pls help me?  1) https://stackoverflow.com/q/60296980/11697039 2)https://stackoverflow.com/q/60293616/11697039

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have any experience with Magento integration.