# Magento 1.9 - OroCRM update sync not working properly

Tags: magento, synchronization, magento-1.9, savechanges, orocrm

After change customer details from magento 1.9 changes not reflect on OroCRM almost 2 days over still not changes not reflect on OroCRM. How to do auto sync in every changes at the same time.